# keep mouse focus in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a login screen which uses `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`. I have a gif image which disappears when the mouse is hovering, and appears when the cursor is on a different part of the page, to allow the user to enter their id and password. The issue is that when I type part of the password, then move my mouse away, the caret focus is lost.

Here is my codes :

```
<div ID="contDefine" class="wipeForward" onmouseenter="fnToggleDefine1()" onmouseleave="fnToggleDefine2()">
<div ID="oDivDefine1" STYLE="position:absolute; width:454px; height:262px; background:#eff0f0 url('image/outlogin.gif') top repeat-x; ">   </div>
<div ID="oDivDefine2" STYLE="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; width:454px; height:262px; background: #eff0f0 url('image/inlogin.gif') top repeat-x; ">

function fnToggleDefine1() {
    if(agent.is_ie && !agent.is_ie10){
        contDefine.className='wipeForward';
        contDefine.filters[0].Apply();
        contDefine.filters[0].Play(duration=1);
    }
    oDivDefine2.style.visibility="visible"; 
    oDivDefine1.style.visibility="hidden";
}

function fnToggleDefine2() {
    if(agent.is_ie && !agent.is_ie10){
        contDefine.className='wipeReverse';
        contDefine.filters[0].Apply();
        contDefine.filters[0].Play(duration=1);
    }
    oDivDefine2.style.visibility="hidden"; 
    oDivDefine1.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

[image]

[image]

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Edited: if u see 2nd image, the caret focus still there (in textbox) when i typing the password, but when i move away my cursor to outside image, its will be like 1st image, the textbox will be blocked by gif image, when i move my cursor inside the image, then should be like 2nd image but the caret focus is disappeared like this

[image]

**UPDATED :**
Since my website only works in IE, i tried to change my JS function

```
function fnToggleDefine2() {
    if(agent.is_ie && !agent.is_ie10){
        contDefine.className='wipeReverse';
        contDefine.filters[0].Apply();
        contDefine.filters[0].Play(duration=1);
    }
    oDivDefine2.style.opaciy="0";
    oDivDefine2.style.zIndex="-999";
    oDivDefine1.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Yes, i want like that, but its seems opacity & zIndex does not work perfectly on IE, and caret focus keep appears eventhough the textbox blocked by image.

Please refer this image :

[image]

Note : For peoples does not understand with my question, please refer to Shuvro comment below.

Comment: Could you put this in a JSFiddle? It's not clear what you're saying.

Comment: Try using `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: agent is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (i cant understand your question, i think you need like this one)
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/jqo8kqnu/)

```
<ul class="demo-2 effect">
    <li>
       <h2 class="zero">This is example!</h2>
       <p class="zero">Happy New Year</p>
    </li>
    <li><img class="top" src="http://s9.postimg.org/z8g84vbej/happy_new_year_2016_wallpapers.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.demo-2 {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:rgba(26,76,110,0.5)
}
.demo-2 p,.demo-2 h2 {
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    left:-20px;
    top:20px;
    position:relative
}
.demo-2 p {
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0
}
.demo-2 h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:'Lato'
}
.effect img {width:200px; height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:-12px 0;
    -webkit-transition:bottom .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:bottom .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:bottom .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:bottom .3s ease-in-out
}
.effect img.top:hover {
    bottom:-96px;
    padding-top:100px
}
h2.zero,p.zero {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

Comment: yes, similar like that, but the image not move down, the image become visible / hide when cursor move in

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using only CSS. No JS needed. Check out the below code -

```css
#box {
  width: 342;
  height: 160;
}

#box:hover > #imgover {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -999;
}

#imgover {
  width: 342;
  height: 160;
  position: absolute;
}

#input-field {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" id="imgover" />
  <input type="text" id="input-field" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you really want to keep the JS try usin the javascript `focus()` method on your input field inside your onmouseenter event. For more information on `focus()` visit [**this link**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp). But the following solution will only work for a single input field. If you can create a fiddle for me in [**jsfiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) I can give you a complete solution using javascript too.

```
function fnToggleDefine1() {    
if(agent.is_ie && !agent.is_ie10){
    contDefine.className='wipeForward';
    contDefine.filters[0].Apply();
    contDefine.filters[0].Play(duration=1);
}
oDivDefine2.style.visibility="visible"; 
oDivDefine1.style.visibility="hidden";
var inputField = document.getElementById("YOUR-INPUT-FIELD-ID-TO-FOCUS-ON");
inputField.focus();
}
```

But for me setting opacity is the correct way because sometimes setting visibility won't work in all browsers causing a flickering.

```js
function hideBox(box) {
  var container = document.getElementById("input-container");
  var image = document.getElementById("imgover");
  container.style.opacity = "1";
  image.style.opacity = "0";
  image.style.zIndex = "-999";
}

function showBox(box) {
  var container = document.getElementById("input-container");
  var image = document.getElementById("imgover");
  container.style.opacity = "0";
  image.style.opacity = "1";
  image.style.zIndex = "999";
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 342;
  height: 160;
}

#imgover {
  width: 342;
  height: 160;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onmouseenter="hideBox(this)" onmouseleave="showBox(this)">
  <img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/demo-sign-d-letter-blocks-forming-isolated-white-background-36021240.jpg" id="imgover" />
  <div id="input-container">
    <input type="text" id="input-field" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great, may i ask u, which part to make the cursor keep focus and is it still effect if i have more than 1 textbox (ex : 3 textboxes) ?. Thanks alot

Comment: @Beginner That's the best part, no additional code needed to refocus, the textbox will never lose focus until you click somewhere else (the default behavior) and yes you can add as many textbox you want one textbox wont lose focus until any other dom element is clicked.

Comment: if i want to use my existing codes on my top post (include the JS method), is it possible to make it like u did? maybe i need to add some codes? and if its default behavior, can i know, what's wrong with my codes to make focus disappears ? Thanks Alot

Comment: Dear Shuvro, its okay if does no work at all browser, since this website only support for IE and as long as its works in IE, no problem for me. i tried with your solution, ya it works with 1 textbox only, but even we have not click the textbox before, its always auto focus. by the way, i already create https://jsfiddle.net/ft9bog5s/ but sorry seems the image did not appear